# Allow someone else edit an album on Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

Is it possible to allow someone else to edit photos within a specific Google+ album? Like adding a legend or a location for the photo(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible on personal profiles, for security and privacy reasons. 
On a business Page the appointed managers can all edit the photos in the Pages' albums.

People can comment on the photos but that's all.

More about Google+ Photos [here](http://googleplushelper.blogspot.fi/2013/06/google-and-your-photos.html).